# Downloading .php file instead of .pdf file when I click download in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

After a lot of struggle I am able to store pdf files into MySql database and can open them in browser by retriving then. My problem is when I click download option, it is getting download as .php file where as it has to get downloaded in .pdf format. Can any one help me here. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$id =  $_POST["iid"];` 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");
mysqli_select_db($link,"test");
$sql = "SELECT image FROM test_image WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($link,"$sql");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
mysqli_close($link);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
echo $row['image'];
?>
```

Comment: How are you getting the file? Show us some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the correct header to download the file.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
echo $pdf
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You should store file in some folder not in database.

Store file's name or url in database.

For example,

If you store file on download folder, and store filename in database, then the download link html like this:

```
<a href="/download/the_file_name_you_want_to _download.pdf" download>
```

You may check out [HTML  download Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: Yeah thank you for your reply. In my case my server is my local machine as I did not host anything. I use xampp. If i store files in some folder with particular file and if later i want to move all my files and pages to some other system, then do i need to change the url according to that system?

Comment: Do't need to change url If you are using [Relative Paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)